# There seems to be a bug in the code when changing the width of lines using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Using Logger.log to find the width of a line returns a number, 0.75 in my case.
`Logger.log(SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2b1b713b937_0_0').asLine().getWeight());`

When that code is adjusted to set the weight of the line I get an erorr message I can't account for.
`SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2b1b713b937_0_0').asLine().getWeight().setWeight(2);`

`.setWeight is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is

```
SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2b1b713b937_0_0').asLine().getWeight()
```

Returns a number so chaining `.setWeight()` will return an error because there is no `.setWeight()` methof of `Number`.

I believe what you want to do is

```
SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2b1b713b937_0_0').asLine().setWeight(2);
```

Comment: Marvellous, that's sorted it - thanks..